# phonegap application containing SQLite database testing by qunit

Tags: javascript, cordova, qunit

I am new to qunit.
   How to test phonegap application containing SQLite database coding  by qunit?

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options:

1. Test on the actual device.  To do this you just need to create a test version of your app that includes the QUnit index.html as your initial page.
2. Test on the desktop.  We've been using PhoneGap for a while and I always create a desktop equivalent for every plugin that we use and substitute a special cordova.js file when running on the desktop.  To emulate SQLite I created a simple web service that accepts SQL statements and returns the results and then updated my cordova.js file to wrap this web service and emulate the Cordova API.

The code for 2 isn't trivial and probably a bit too involved to post here, but I personally find it worth the investment as it allows you to do all of your initial development and testing in the desktop environment.